# Finding an area under the curve with no area

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, area, planar-graphs

Hello I am trying to explain why the function h(x)

$h(x)= x^{99} + x$

will always have the area without determining an antiderivative of h(x) that we must have

[image]

First I thought of drawing the graph and noticed that the area under the curve on the right side will be identical to the area above the curve on the left side.

I am not sure how to explain in detail why the area bounded by b,-b will always equal to 0.

[image]

Comment: Perhaps the magic word is **antisymmetric**

Comment: Also, it's a polynomial so integration should be a no-brainer, right?

Comment: It is an odd function, that's why the integral is zero

Answer (score 1):

Clearly $h(x)$ is an odd function, that is $h(x)=-h(-x)$ for all $x$. Thus we have $$\int_{-b}^{b}h(x)dx=\int_{0}^{b}h(x)dx+\int_{-b}^{0}h(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{b}h(x)dx-\int_{-b}^{0}h(-x)dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{b}h(x)dx+\int_{b}^{0}h(x)dx$$
$$=\int_{0}^{b}h(x)dx-\int_{0}^{b}h(x)dx=0.$$